# Azure Data Factory - What is the fastest way to copy a lot of files from OnPrem to blob storage when they are deeply nested

Tags: azure-data-factory

I must get to two different excel files that are nested within 360 parent directories XXXX with a \ME (Month End directory) then a year directory, and finally a yyyymm directory.
Example: Z500\ME\2022\202205\Z500_contributions_202205.xls.

I tried with the copy data activity and killed it after it was still spinning on the listing source step. I thought about the lookup and metadata activities and those have limits of 5000 rows. Any thoughts on what would be the fastest way to do this?

Code for creating the filelist. I'll clean the results up in Excel
dir L:*.xls /s /b > "C:\Foo.txt"

Right now I am creating a list of files with the DOS dir command and hoping that if I have a filelist with the copy activity that it will runs faster if it doesn't have to go through the "list sources" step and interrogate the filesystem.

Thoughts on a ADF option?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues with **`copy activity`**, instead you can try **`azcopy`** which also can be used for copying from OnPrem to Blob storage.
You can try the below code:

```
azcopy copy "local path/*" "https://<storage account
name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name><path to blob" --recursive=true --include-pattern "*.xlsx"
```

Please go through this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-migrate-on-premises-data?tabs=windows) to know how to use azcopy.

The above script **copies all the excel files from nested folders** recursively. But it also copies the folders to the blob storage as well.

After copying to blob storage, you can use the `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` in the Powershell to list out all the excel files in the nested folders to a single folder.

```
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy  -SrcFile $sourcefile -DestCloudBlob “Destination path”
```

Please refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72450355/delete-files-older-than-1-year-from-azure-file-storage-with-runbook/72461396#72461396) to list out the files in the blob recursively.

If you are creating list of files in OnPrem then you can use either **azcopy** or **copy activity** as your wish.

**Please check these screenshots of `azcopy` for your reference:**

[image]

Here I am using azcopy with SAS. You can use it in both ways with SAS and with Active Directory as mentioned in the documentation above.

**Excel file in Blob storage:**

[image]