# Extracting Files from Onprem server to Azure Blob storage while filtering files with no data

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, etl, azure-data-factory

I am trying to transfer on-premise files to azure blob storage. However, out of the 5 files that I have, 1 has "no data" so I can't map the schema. Is there a way I can filter out this file while importing it to azure? Or would I have to import them into azure blob storage as is then filter them to another blob storage? If so, how would I do this?

[DataPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iilrk.png)
[CompleteFiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SwmV.png) [Nodata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCVGI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your on prem source is your local file system, then first copy the files with folder structure to a temporary blob container using `azcopy` SAS key. Please refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72622692/azure-data-factory-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-copy-a-lot-of-files-from-onprem/72645734#72645734) to know about it.

Then use ADF pipeline to filter out the empty files and store it final blob container.

These are my files in blob container and `sample2.csv` is an empty file.

[image]

First use Get Meta data activity to get the files list in that container.

[image]

It will list all the files and give that array to the ForEach as `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

Inside ForEach use **lookup** to get the row count of every file and if the `count !=0` then use copy activity to copy the files.

Use dataset parameter to give the file name.

[image]

Inside if give the below condition.

```
@not(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.count,0))
```

[image]

Inside True activities use copy activity.

[image]

copy sink to another blob container:

[image]

Execute this pipeline and you can see the empty file is filtered out.

[image]

If your on-prem source is SQL, use **lookup** to get the list of tables and then use ForEach. Inside ForEach do the same procedure for individual tables.

If your on-prem source other than the above mentioned also, first try to copy all files to blob storage then follow the same procedure.

Comment: Instead of using az copy, can I use "copy data" with a tumbling window to import the files into blob from onprem? These files will be generating once a week and I need them to full the latest file

Comment: I'm also confused about this part 
" Inside ForEach use lookup to get the row count of every file and if the count !=0 then use copy activity to copy the files.

Use dataset parameter to give the file name."

Where do I put the "count !=0"? 

Also, where can I find "Use dataset parameter to give the file name."? When I select "Lookup 1" and select "Settings" I only get file path type, and not "Name and Value"

Comment: Answer to first question- Yeah, it depends on your on prem, if your on prem is a local file system you can use File system linked service with copy activity first to copy the files to blob then use the above to filter empty files.

Comment: In the If activity expression we are checking whether the count is 0 or not based on lookup output. If not, then we are using copy activity inside the if True activities. And in lookup or copy activity, to get the Parameters like that, first you need to create a dataset parameter in the dataset like this https://i.imgur.com/wUgj3RN.png. Then give that parameter in the dataset file path like this https://i.imgur.com/tKIXYF6.png. Now it will show the Dataset properties in the activities. Do the same for sink Dataset also in the copy activity.

Comment: Thank you for the info Rakesh, you are helping me greatly. In the first picture, the location is "inputadf"  but in the second photo you are pulling data from "Mydataset", how does this work? Shouldn't the metadata be pulled from "inputadf"?

Comment: "Mydataset" is only the name of the dataset in that. The pictures in the comments are given only for sample on how to get the dataset parameter in the activities. For Meta data activity I have used another dataset with only path till 'inputadf'(container). for lookup and copy activity I have used another dataset.

Comment: For lookup and copy activity I need the path to file name(like `inputadf/sample1.csv`) dynamically. So thats why used another dataset with parameter.

Comment: You are filtering out a completely blank file, but I need to filter out files the have "no data" in one of the cells as per the image attached in the original post. So would then "@not(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.count,0))" be different since I'm filtering out something else?

Comment: Ok change the condition as per your requirement, like `@not(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.count,1))` in this case as 'no data' will counted as one row and remaining other files will have more than one row.

Comment: I created a "copy data" pipeline from onprem files to blob storage, should I create a new pipeline for the filtering process or should I just connect "copy data - get metadata"?

Comment: When I execute the pipeline, this is the error message that appears: 
"The expression 'not(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.count,1))' cannot be evaluated because property 'count' doesn't exist, available properties are 'firstRow, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'."
Should I select "firstRow" since the "no data" cell is in the first row?

Comment: As you want to trigger this pipeline, connect the filtering process to this copy activity. But make sure you are giving the correct container name in Get Meta data activity which is created by first copy activity.

Comment: don't select firstRow, and execute.

Comment: Hey Rakesh, I have created a google docs where I shared my entire process from start to finish. If you have the time, would you able to go in and see what I'm messing up? Here is the link, please let me know if you need anything else: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JfHxY-EBg9uCeT9GiwDNwlxdvzmSeOPUxNVGfcDm7Ro/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: unselect the firstRow only in the lookup activity. also, if you use wild card path it won't give the count for individual files. Use the dataset parameter in the lookup and copy activity source and give `@item().name` which will give each files name so that we can get the file Row count in each iteration.

Comment: I deselected the firstRow. Also, when I deselect wildcard path, It doesn't let me publish it. I have attached an updated image to the google docs at the bottom. Do these errors mean I have to create a paramater for blobcontainer2, the destination for the onprem files?

Comment: As I mentioned in the above comments use another dataset for that temporary container and create parameter for it. For Get Meta Data we need container. But for lookup and copy activity we need file path so use another dataset for it with parameter like above.

Comment: How do I create a temporary container? I don't see the option

Comment: temporary container means the same container that we are using for storing on-prem to blob files without filterng.

Comment: Would you be able to hop on a teams call Rakesh? I'm not understanding how to use the on-prem to blob files as a folder and temporary container at the same time. If you are able to hop on a call, please leave an email in the google docs and I'll send a teams invite whenever works for you

Comment: In the first copy activity sink you are copying the files from on-prem to a blob container right. Use the same dataset in Get Meta data activity. But for lookup and 2nd copy activity source create another dataset and give the same blob container name first(for me its inputadf here https://i.imgur.com/tKIXYF6.png) and use the dataset paremeter like above and give `item().name` for that in the activities.

Comment: I created a new dataset for lookup and 2nd copy activity. I posted both in the google docs, however, I'm getting an error when I trigger it

Comment: Please deselect the FirstRow only in the lookup activity and try again.

Comment: I deselcted and triggered the pipeline only to get this error: "Operation on target ForEach1 failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed; Inner activity name: Lookup1, Error: ErrorCode=UserErrorSourceBlobNotExist,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The required Blob is missing. ContainerName: https://threebearsblob.blob.core.windows.net/inputadf, path: daily (4).csv.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source

Comment: for me, the container name is `inputadf`. You have copied the files from on-prem to a blob container. Use the same container name in the dataset.

Comment: I change both from inputadf to blob_container2. However, it doesn't let me publish the changes because blob_container2 is a folder amongst other problems. I have attached an image of the failed validation changes in the google docs along with my change

Comment: Can you share a picture of your entire data factory that way I can see the pipeline and the datasets you are using?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments Rakesh, in your example you have five datasets 
1. inputadf
2. mydataset
3. sourcedata_for_files
4. delimitedtext2
5. sinkadf
Why is there so many? I struggling to see why so many are needed